# SKIP LOCKED ... FOR UPDATE degrading performance with other unrelated activity in the write replica

Tags: postgresql-11, amazon-rds-aurora

We have a workload running in RDS Aurora Postgresql (v11) modelled around the transactional outbox pattern. Roughly, X workers will open a transaction, query a table for the most recent non-locked row and lock it with FOR UPDATE (using SKIP LOCKED), delete them, and perform some work (i.e. send some message to a broker) before committing the transaction. The queries look roughly like this:

```
SELECT id FROM outbox WHERE ( ( outbox . attempts < 10 ) AND ( ( outbox . run_at IS NULL ) OR ( outbox . run_at < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ) ) ORDER BY run_at DESC NULLS FIRST, id LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED

-- and when the query returns a result

DELETE FROM outbox WHERE ( id IN ( ? ) ) RETURNING *
```

This aurora cluster where this database is deployed is a "shared" cluster, i.e. many services use it for their own database. This means that there's some noisy neighbour effect going on in a few situations, particularly in the workload of some other service with a misbehaving query which locks a few rows for a couple of minutes at a time.

Periodically, we start noticing significant performance degradation in the outbox-related queries. This usually manifests in the queries progressively taking longer to execute, and after a certain threshold we're forced to run a `VACUUM FULL outbox` to bring it back into shape (sometimes multiple times during a day).

What we notice during those periods is that the write replica monitors show concerning numbers when it comes to "transaction logs disk usage" or "disk depth" or "max transaction ids"; particular "transaction logs disk usage" seems to grow linearly during these incidents.

My hypothesis is that the grown in transaction logs means that WAL logs aren't being applied, and therefore queries relying on particular transaction work must scrape several WAL logs before presenting results. This is somehow correlated with the tuples from previous transaction tuples which didn't get cleaned up, and that's because regular VACUUM can't be run periodically until the WAL logs are applied. The fact that outbox workload must run in transactions seems to contribute to this scenario somehow.

Sysadmins also mention something about DMS tasks / logical replication happening, which may contribute to transaction logs overhead. I didn't buy it much in the case of LR, but perhaps DMS tasks are a factor, and somehow they can't get to the finish line because of that long running transaction above?

Any pointers appreciated.